# why postgres queries on table with jsonb column are slow even if it's not used in query

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with a `jsonb` coumn that contains some average sized jsons, 1-3k characters, nothing crazy. The table had ~5m rows when queries suddenly went from seconds to minutes. At 6m it was pretty much unusable anymore. Even a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders` is now taking unreasonably long `execution: 10 m 8 s 638 ms, fetching: 25 ms`. Plenty of free disk space and memory on the AWS RDS instance.

I recall from older versions of mysql (possibly postgres too?), best practice was to split out columns containing large blobs of data into separate tables to avoid the engine having to read it all when doing a full table scan, but these days are gone and optimisers are clever enough to not read these columns from disk if they're not used in the query itself. Or so I thought.

Postgres seems to be using [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-toast.html) for values larger than 8kB, but I'm not sure `jsonb` columns are subject to it and our jsons don't seem to exceed that either so that's probably the wrong tree to bark at.

I've seen a few updates to the table happening in parallel which seem to be really slow too, but only a couple per minute. And I cannot think of a reason why an update row lock would slow down a count on a primary key.

Can anyone please shed some light why the performance of a table with `jsonb` can be so terrible and drop so rapidly regardless if I even query for it? And possibly, how can I improve it to support a larger number of records?

Postgres 10

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    ext_id varchar,
    source varchar,
    -- few more varchar columns omitted for brevity
    data jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX index_orders_on_ext_id_and_source ON orders (ext_id, source);
```

EXPLAIN with ~6m rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders

5763960

1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 10 m 39 s 248 ms (execution: 10 m 39 s 215 ms, fetching: 33 ms)

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders

Aggregate  (cost=577200.38..577200.39 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders  (cost=0.43..562797.62 rows=5761104 width=0)

2 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 30 ms (execution: 17 ms, fetching: 13 ms)
```

EXPLAIN after simply reducing data in the table to ~1m rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders

1033030

1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 173 ms (execution: 158 ms, fetching: 15 ms)

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders

Aggregate  (cost=146889.05..146889.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=411.111..411.111 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=279187 read=3239
  ->  Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders  (cost=0.42..144302.28 rows=1034708 width=0) (actual time=0.014..304.558 rows=1033525 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 12139
        Buffers: shared hit=279187 read=3239
Planning time: 0.054 ms
Execution time: 411.142 ms

7 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 442 ms (execution: 428 ms, fetching: 14 ms)
```

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question and show us the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` (rather than a "simple" explain)

Comment: I could only update the EXPLAIN with 1m records, production was impaired so we had to take some quick action and delete redundant records. I'm guessing this isn't helpful to you at all now, appologies. I'll see if I can restore a backup in a separate instance and run it there.

Comment: As a guess, I would say that your autovacuum settings are not aggressive enough to keep up with the update activity on your table.  It will be difficult to verify that with fewer rows now, but you could still figure out what the settings are and keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2):

TOAST works with JSONB.  If it did not, you would not be able to store any JSONB more than 8kB in size. But that is not where TOAST kicks in, it kicks in around 2000B.  So with a range of 1kB to 3kB some of your data is toasted and some is not.

But this doesn't seem to be relevant.  According to your plan, "Index Only Scan using orders_pkey", it shouldn't need to access the heap (if the table is well vacuumed), much less the TOAST.  We don't know what is going on, but it seems to have nothing to do with JSONB specifically.

You might want to set up [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auto-explain.html) now, so that if something like this happens again you will have some evidence to work from.

```
track_io_timing=on
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '1s'
auto_explain.log_analyze=on
auto_explain.log_timing=off
auto_explain.log_buffers=on
auto_explain.log_nested_statements=on
```

On some systems, turning log_analyze on without turning log_timing off can cause a large degradation in system performance, which is why I recommend turning it off unless you have researched and decided it is not a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up TOAST behaviour. And seems enabling `auto_explain` is a very usefull advice. I'll enable it now and will update with more details once the table fills up and the problem comes back again.

Comment: Also, you're probably right that `JSONB` isn't the culrpit at all because upon restoring a snapshot to a separate instance, I couldn't get that `COUNT` query (which took 10m on prod) to run for more than 10s.

Comment: @VigintasLabakojis: sounds as if your table was bloated: https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/checking-for-postgresql-bloat or https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/estimating-table-bloat/

Comment: @VigintasLabakojis  did you do a logical restore (like from pg_dump) or a physical restore (like from pg_basebackup)?

Comment: @jjanes it was an AWS RDS "restore from backup" mechanism, not exactly sure what they use in their backend.